If you use a free icon as a logo, could someone else make a similar business / product with the same icon?
Here's an example: Bitwarden uses a Font Awesome V3 icon which is explicitly allowed for commercial use.

https://fontawesome.com/v3/icon/shield
https://fontawesome.com/v3/license/




The big question is not if someone could use it.. of course they could. The real question is why you would want a "logo" to be so easily replicated?? That's NOT the purpose of a "logo".

In addition, you can't copyright any logo which contains artwork you don't own. Even IF a license permits the use of the artwork - use ≠ ownership.

Yes, they could use same icon. Though the shape is super generic i don't see any value in doing so. But you can trademark Bitwarden name (as seen here)
